# What is a normal entropy_avail value for apache?

Tags: apache, cryptography, entropy

My entropy value is around 130-180 while a test script is running and 150-180 normally.  Would that value have any bearing on static HTML pages that don't use any random() functionality?  Or do all pages rely on the entropy?  Also, what is considered to be a normal value?  I've seen articles stating that value should be around 4094 if nothing is using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh.  I do not know why these programs insist on "true random" numbers when a cryptographic pseudo-RNG is perfectly adequate.

That said, if you install [rng-tools](http://raventools.com/blog/apache-hangs-due-to-lack-of-entropy/) (or whatever package contains rngd), you will not have to worry about this.  (Because the CPU has a hardware RNG built in.)

I guess I am assuming this is a Linux system and a reasonably modern CPU.

Comment: I installed that and it didn't help any.  I did install haveged and that increased it to 2000-4000.  So that increased it, but it didn't help with my core issue anyways.  At least I have lots of entropy now.

Comment: Once you are using the hardware RNG, the /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail value is actually irrelevant.